# AirBnb Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen-visas, airbnb

Is AirBnb categorized as "hotel" or "staying with a person" for schengen visa online application from India? I am confused about putting hotel name and other details like phone number and email. Staying with a person probably means without paying, but I paid for AirBnb. Please help.